# Error while using a parameter within the id of a called azure function from a logic app

Tags: azure-functions, azure-logic-apps

I have different azure functions in different stages,
when i deploy my logic app i would like to configure what azure function is called.

I added a new parameter called:

```
"unzip_gzip_path": {
      "value": "/subscriptions/XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX/resourceGroups/XXXTest/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites/FunctionApp201806XXXXXXXX/functions/Function1"
    }
```

And use him in the arm template like this:

```
"$functions_paths": {
            "value": {
              "unzip_gzip": {
                "path": "[parameters('unzip_gzip_path')]"
              }
            }
          }
```

The Azure function call goes like this:

```
"Function1":{
                      "type": "Function",
                      "inputs": {
                        "body": "@items('For_each_attachment')?['ContentBytes']",
                        "method": "POST",
                        "function": {
                          "id": "@parameters('$functions_paths')['unzip_gzip']['path']"
                        }
                      },
                      "runAfter": {}
                    }
```

Now I am getting the error

```
15:31:34 - 15:31:33 - Resource Microsoft.Logic/workflows 'DMARCReportingProcessingLogicApp' failed with message '{
15:31:34 -   "error": {
15:31:34 -     "code": "LinkedInvalidPropertyId",
15:31:34 -     "message": "Property id '@parameters('$functions_paths')['unzip_gzip']['path']' at path 'properties.definition.actions.For_each_attachment.actions.Condition.actions.Function1.inputs.function.id' is invalid. Expect fully qualified resource Id that start with '/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}' or '/providers/{resourceProviderNamespace}/'."
15:31:34 -   }
15:31:34 - }'
```

Could it be that I can not use parameters within the function location?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Currently the resource ID of the function can only be set at deploy-time and not runtime.  The right way to set it is as an ARM parameter and not a logic app parameter if that makes sense.

[Here's an example](https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/blob/master/101-logic-app-and-function-app/azuredeploy.json) of one that is parameter-ized for deployment.

`{
            "Azure_Function": {
              "type": "Function",
              "inputs": {
                "body": "@triggerBody()",
                "function": {
                  "id": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/sites/functions', parameters('functionAppName'), variables('functionName'))]"
                }
              },
              "runAfter": {}
            }`

Comment: Hi Jeff, it'd be great if using Logic Apps params was supported, as requested here. https://feedback.azure.com/forums/287593-logic-apps/suggestions/32849239-allow-calling-functions-and-nested-logic-apps-usin
This would really help to make easier to prepare ARM templates for Logic Apps, Cheers :)

Comment: In general the gap today is that Functions can’t be dynamic at run time. Not sure what parameters would bring for deploy-time which should be possible today (for what it’s worth I believe making them dynamic at runtime also being worked on)